# Kentico Page preview not working for imported pages

Tags: kentico

I've got an issue where our manually added pages are working fine in the preview, but a number of pages that we imported using the Kentico Import Toolkit (9.0) aren't showing up in the preview. Now I did Automatically publish pages under a workflow, but I didn't set any specific fields in the import for a preview url.

Is there a field I need to set for the preview functionality to work??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "aren't showing up in the preview" mean exactly? Can you provide some more details or a screenshot?

Comment: It was erroring out because it was going to the wrong url, sorry I should have been clearer on that.  I managed to figure it out though,  going to post the fix below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using a content only page type and it was causing the url for the preview to be wrong.  Once I set the NodeIsContentOnly flag to true on the import the preview would then work.